# page getting stuck after using for 5 minute

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I have created a page in react+next and it's an exchange for crypto trading, I have multiple issues with the website.
1- it's getting stuck after switching tabs and making the tab inactive for more than 2-3 minutes. We have called a few sockets on our website so we have tried stopping those sockets on tab change but didn't work.
2- also facing the issue of page freeze on the ios browser. In the first load, the page works fine but after the load, it stops updating the socket data.
Does anyone have any idea about it ????

Comment: Please check the console. It is quite possible that you are updating some value in loop i.e. "useState". It's a common mistake. Or post the console, so that someone can help

Comment: If you don't post any code it's almost impossible to guess what's happening...

Comment: if anyone uses iPhone, please open the weblink https://beta.synchrobit.io/user-area/dashboard/user-trade/BTC-USDT and see what exactly happens